# SQL does not connect when published on local IIS on Razor pages project using entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, iis, asp.net-core

I am developing razor pages web app that uses Microsoft entity framework that connects to SQL server. It all works in when running straight from visual studio (IIS Express), but when I tried to deploy it on IIS, SQL connection no longer worked.

connection strings i have tried:

```
Server=localhost;Database=zzzz;Trusted_Connection=True;
Server=DESKTOP-R7J0NGU;Database=zzzz;User Id=yyyy;Password=xxxx;
```

The application deployed on IIS does not give any information what is causing a problem, is it server, is it database, or authentication problem.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you checked Windows Event Logs -> Application Logs for any errors/more information? Also is this IIS hosted site still local on your machine or is this another server?

Comment: Do you know if your SQL server is set to allow remote connections? And is your server value the actual name of the SQL Server instance, and not just the name of the machine it's on?

Comment: the event viewer gave: 
```
Login succeeded for user 'yyyy'. Connection made using SQL Server authentication. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bother anyone.
the connection string has worked:

```
Server=DESKTOP-R7J0NGU;Database=zzzz;User Id=yyyy;Password=xxxx;
```

the problem was that the user "yyyy" did not have correct permissions to see and modify database tables. It did cost long time figuring out because my application in release build did not give any information as to why it might have failed.